# "LOCAL_ONE" read consistency in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlConfigConsistency.html As mentioned in the link, read consistency level 'LOCAL_ONE' means that the response from the closest replica in the local datacenter is returned. However, I don't understand which is the local datacenter? Is it the one, to which the coordinator node belongs?

Answer (score 3):

If you build your cassandra session you can define the load-balancing policy. If you don’t explicitly configure the policy, you get the default, which is a datacenter-aware, token-aware policy:

```
new TokenAwarePolicy(DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.builder().build());
```

This defaults to something like this:

```
Cluster cluster = Cluster.builder()
        .addContactPoint("127.0.0.1")
        .withLoadBalancingPolicy(
                DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.builder()
                        .withLocalDc("myLocalDC")
                        .withUsedHostsPerRemoteDc(2)
                        .allowRemoteDCsForLocalConsistencyLevel()
                        .build()
        ).build();
```

And you should set `.withLocalDc()` to your local (aka nearest) datacenter otherwise the driver will pick the datacenter from the first contact point.

(see: http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/load_balancing)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's the dc that the node belongs to.

A write with a consistency level of LOCAL_ONE must be sent to, and successfully acknowledged by, at least one replica node in the local datacenter. If the write consistency level is LOCAL_ONE or LOCAL_QUORUM, only the nodes in the same datacenter as the coordinator node must respond to the client request in order for the request to succeed.

Read this for further info. [Multiple datacenter write requests](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlClientRequestsMultiDCWrites.html)

For a read with a consistency level of LOCAL_ONE, returns a response from the closest replica, as determined by the snitch, but only if the replica is in the local data center. The closest replica for the given row in the same datacenter as the coordinator node is contacted to fulfill the read request. In the background a read repair is potentially initiated, based on the read_repair_chance setting of the table, for the other replicas.

Read this for further info: [A two datacenter cluster with a consistency level of LOCAL_ONE](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlClientRequestsReadExp.html#dmlClientRequestsReadExp__two-dc-local-one)

Comment: Jow to decide which one is the local data center for a random request from client

Comment: Got it. any node that received the request is the coordinator node. the data center which the coordinator node is in  is considered as the local data center for much request